# Enabling PHP Code Assist for different PECL extensions in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, pecl

I'm using a few PECL installed extensions in my PHP environment. I am developing with Eclipse and it would be useful to have Eclipse's code assist / auto-completion support for these extensions. This procedure worked quite well for the [Solr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) extension:

1. I additionally downloaded the latest [solr-php PECL sources](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr/0.9.11) and put them into a separate folder.
2. I added this certain folder as an "external folder" to one of my User Libs (Prefrences -> PHP -> PHP Libraries).
3. I added the user lib to my project's php include path (Properties -> PHP Include Path -> Libraries -> Add Library)
4. I immediately had the new classes/methods available in the editor's auto-completion.

The problem is: This doesn't seem to work for all extensions. E. g. for the [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) adding MongoDB support to PHP. Why is that?

Comparing the folders' contents I notice that the Mongo extension is missing a php file like docs/documentation.php (which is contained in the Solr extension). Whereas all relevant *.h and *.c files are available.

Do I have to generate certain file(s) by myself?

Thanks in advance for your hints, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the question at mongodb's user group I got a link containing *.php doc files for the mongo php driver, which solved my problem after including them in my eclipse/pdt environment.

- [discussion at mongodb user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/jcBok8-jfVs/CyLM0Qsjl34J)
- [mongo php driver doc packages](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/?package_id=10756)

A [generate.php](http://git.eclipse.org/c/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/Resources/language/) script is offered by the pdt project, the new link was given by @ss333 below.

Comment: I suggest you here or in question post some result => just link to only needed *.php file(-s), that other can use in the future. By link I mean only one link :)

Comment: The second link to sourceforge.jp is dead. Please fix. Thanks!

Comment: After a couple of hours Googling, the new link is: [Eclipse PDT generate.php](http://git.eclipse.org/c/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/Resources/language/)

Comment: Please download the 'generate.php' in any local directory, then just run it using command line e.g `/usr/bin/php generate.php -split` and it would automatically create all the skeleton code for all the modules currently loaded in php, then just  create a php project in eclipse and add the location of the generated files, as needed, in your include path.

Comment: generate.php seems to require you to download and extract the ENTIRE PHP documentation somewhere and tell it where you extracted it. This is a prohibitive prerequisite.

Comment: This solution is outdated and no current solution seems to be known. The furthest I got is to get the generate.php script to roughly-aboutly recognize the given source documentation directory as the right one, but then it just spat out hundreds of lines like `Documentation for <module name> not exists!', for Every. Last. Module.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... May be using sources instead of *.php classes?

Or just mongo don`t have such good piece of *.php, like in Solr.

And I think it shouldn`t have...

As I understand -- it's somekind of extension, which is not bundled with PHP by default, so then we don't have such a nice stuff, like for some php.core, when we click on `realpath`.

I suggest here to add some bug to mongo team and maybe to fix it by some patch, that will be analog of the solr solution. Yes -- you should add it by yourself. Ecl works with *.php files for compeletion in PHP. *.h & *.c will not helps here.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I posted the prob at mongodb's user group and received a useful answer - see my own answer to this question for more info.